# How to refresh the date label in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB and I'm wondering how to do the following:
   I have a (very) basic application which, when launched, shows the current date. However, my application does not update the date when a new day begins at midnight (it will still show the initial date of when the application was launched).

In VB.NET, what code allows my Label's text to update/refresh the date label to get the new date?
Maybe I have to use a timer to do the action when the system time = 0000 etc?
My Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label4.Text = Format(Now, "dddd dd. MMMM yyyy")   
End Sub   
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, use a timer.  Don't be afraid to try...

Comment: ...and dont be afraid to click the checkmark next to the answers which help.

Comment: I have tried timers but I don't know the code that makes the label refresh whenever the system date changes. Would you be able to provide me with some code as I am new to vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**
Use a timer.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Just re-order the formats so it'll fit you.

The time will not only update, but **running**.

Comment: Is there a way to make this date display in the same format as in my example (weekday, date., month, year? If I can achieve this then my question is answered.

Comment: Edited the question for you. Hoped that help you. Just click the big green check mark if my answer works.

Comment: Of course you could just condense the code in the Timer1.Click event to the following;   Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") which will have exactly the same effect.